# Django Meta ordering in related query

Tags: python, django

How do you set a default order for Django queries that works on related managers?

You can set a default order with Meta.ordering:

```
class Subject(Model):
    title = TextField()

class Course(Model):
    subject = ForeignKey(Subject)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

This will set the order when you run `Course.objects.all()`. But when you run `subject.course_set.all()`, the courses can be out of order.

Ideally, a solution would involve no changes to the vast existing codebase that queries the db.

Note: The database is Postgresql

Comment: `subject.course_set.all()` would also be ordered. How do you know that it is not?

Comment: I ran it. Interestingly, it was **reversed** ordered. The subjects were ordered by id **ascending** when queried with ```Subject.objects.all()``` and the courses were ordered by id **descending** when queried with ```subject.course_set.all()```.

Comment: `subject.course_set.all()` would have the same order as the ordering that you set in your `Course` model, it is not the case for you?

Comment: It isn't the case. Interestingly, it's reversed. When I query ```Course.objects.all()``` it returns ids in ascending order as desired. When I query ```subject.course_set.all()``` it returns them in **descending** order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, there is a hack
You can make a manager method like

```
class SomeManagerSet(models.QuerySet):
    def ordered(self):
        return self.order_by("id")
```

And activate it in model via

```
objects = SomeManagerSet.as_manager()
```

And then use in related query like `subject.course_set.ordered()`

Comment: Ok...is there a non-hacky way to do this? This also requires changing all existing query code.

Comment: You can rewrite `all()` method in this case you won't need to rewrite all existing code

Comment: I think you can specify a manager class in the ``Meta`` class, which can implement this behaviour.

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi You can't just rewrite ```all```: you'd have to rewrite ```filter```, ```order_by```, and all the other methods.

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/